# Wake On Lan doesn't work on Repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, lan, wake-on-lan

I've been trying to use Wake-On-Lan on my dual boot (Debian+Win 10) PC. But, even after following all steps (enabling WoL in BIOS) , it's not working. I thought that maybe magic packets weren't reaching my computer on Port 9. So, I used tcpdump, and yes, the packets are reaching successfully (at least when the computer is booted up already).

One difference I noticed in my case as compared to the ideal situation is that my computer's LAN cable is connected to a Repeater instead of the main router. Could this be the source of the problem?

Here's an image of the setup, as asked for in comments
[image]

Comment: The repeater must support [Subnet Directed Broadcasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Subnet_directed_broadcasts).

Comment: A WLAN repeater? WLAN does not support WOL, you'll need to use a Ethernet cable.

Comment: @Albin It's TP-Link Archer C20

Comment: as I said, it won't work (see answer).

Comment: Can you wake up the computer with a different method (USB, Timer, etc.)? How did you setup the WOL-tool on your mobil (specificly what's the target MAC and what's MAC of your wired NIC, does the computer have any other NICs, etc. - errors won't show up in the packet grabber, since magic packets are broadcasted)?

Comment: Also: what steps did you take to set up the WOL on the PC (add them to your question)?

Comment: @Albin The target MAC is the MAC as shown in DHCP stats of the main router

Comment: You need to add the requested information to your question, otherwise there are too many open variables (despite correct configurations there is loads of stuff that can be configured incorrectly causing the issues)

Answer (score 1):

**New answer**: No, since you verified that the magic packets arrive at the target PC the wireless extender shouldn't be the problem. Other than that more info is needed to answer the question (see comments).

---

**Old answer**, before the question was edited:

Unless the PC is not connected via Ethernet cable the WOL will not work. Wireless adapters are powered down on shutdown and do receive/transmit any singnals (check the AP the PC was connected to and you'll see the PC is not connected via WLAN anymore).

In order to use WOL you need to connect the PC via Ethernet cable (I don't know this specific model but in general it should work being connected to the repeater via a cable as well).

Comment: @FitzWatson I updated, you can delete your comments